# Django QuerySet union operator is not commutative after intersection

Tags: python, django, union, django-queryset, intersection

I use python 3.4.2 and django 2.0.

My models.py

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then in python console I do this:

```
>>>a = Solution.objects.all().filter(id="1")
>>>b = Solution.objects.all().filter(id__in=["1","2"])
>>>c = Solution.objects.all().filter(id="3")
>>>ab = a.intersection(b)
>>>abc = ab.union(c)
>>>cab = c.union(ab)
>>>abc
<QuerySet [<Solution: Solution-id1>, <Solution: Solution-id3>]>
>>>cab
<QuerySet [<Solution: Solution-id1>]>
```

Why abc and bca are different?

If i need to do many intersections and unions operation with my querysets what should i do? Because i expect to have

```
<QuerySet [<Solution: Solution-id1>, <Solution: Solution-id3>]>
```

in any order of union.

I take string with long query from user. For example:

```
(((id 1) and (id 2)) or (id 3)) or ((id 4) and (id 5))
```

And i use recursive function with loops on queryset to search the result.
But if union operator is not commutative i can't predict the result.
I think that I can hit the base everytime, but can I do something on querysets without hiting database?

Comment: Because the order is different?

Comment: Furthermore two exactly the same querysets are not equal either.